# Shift and Alt won't work together in app

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, adobe-photoshop, modifier-keys, transform

I have a weird issue, I think I'm missing something very easy but can't find what.

For years I've been using <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd> to resize an object  transformation anchor in the center and keeping proportions intact. But recently it's not working anymore.

It's either centering the transform anchor (<kbd>alt</kbd>) or keeping the proportions (<kbd>shift</kbd>), whichever I pressed later, but not both at the same time.

The keys are working fine outside of adobe apps.

Any one has a clue?

Comment: The keyboard shortcut is correct, but did you press Ctrl + T before (Transform)?

Comment: About problems with keyboard shortcuts in Photoshop [link](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/kb/keyboard-shortcuts-stop-photoshop-mac.html). Consider also that if the default shortcut doesn't work you can customize it in Edit > Keyboard Shortcuts.

Comment: Spike thank you for your effort but that is not even close to answering the question. I don't have an issue with shortcuts or my keyboard or forgetting to Transform (:S)

As I explained above, I CAN modify my transformation with Alt or Shift individually but NOT Simultaneously.